# Calculations - Javascript - Square feet total divided by square feet and Annual Rent divided by Square Feet

Tags: javascript, html, percentage

I'm trying to have several calculations run.  One of them divides the annual rent by the square feet.  This works unless you add a comma or a dollar sign.  I'd also like the rent/sq ft field to display nothing at all instead of Nan if there isn't something filled in in the fields.   The second field gives a percentage (% NRA) by dividing the total square feet by the sq ft. This I would also like to remain blank if there is not anything in the field.   Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 <html>

 <head>
 <title></title>
```

```
 <body>

<form method="POST" action>


<table border="0" width="640">

  <tr>
    <td width="169"><font face="Arial" size="2">Total Square Feet:</font></td>
    <td width="136"><font size="2" face="Arial">
    <input type="text" name="SF" id="TotalSF" OnChange="calcNRA1();" size="18" tabindex="530"></font></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;
<table border="1" height="167">
  <tr>
    <td width="82" align="center" height="16"><font face="Arial" size="2">Sq.
      Ft.</font></td>
    <td width="61" align="center" height="16"><font face="Arial" size="2">%
      NRA:</font></td>
    <td align="center" height="16" style="width: 106px"><font face="Arial" size="2">Annual
      Rent</font></td>
    <td align="center" height="16" style="width: 129px"><font face="Arial" size="2">&nbsp;
      Rent/Sq. Ft.</font></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="82" align="center" style="height: 23px"><font face="Arial" size="2">
    <input type="text" name="SF_Tenant1" id="sqft1" OnFocus="calcRentSQFTOne()" OnKeyUp="calcRentSQFTOne()"  OnChange="calcNRA1()" size="10" tabindex="602" class="style4"></font></td>
    <td width="61" align="center" style="height: 23px"><font face="Arial" size="2">
    <input type="text" name="PercNRA_Tenant1" id="NRA1" size="7" tabindex="603"></font></td>
    <td style="height: 23px; width: 106px;" class="style5"><font face="Arial" size="2">
    <strong><font size="2">$ </font></strong>
    <!--webbot bot="Validation" s-data-type="Number" s-number-separators=",." --><input type="text" name="AnnualRent_Tenant1" id="annualrent1" OnFocus="calcRentSQFTOne()" onblur="this.value = '$' + formatNumber(this.value, 0, 0, true)"  OnKeyUp="calcRentSQFTOne()" size="11" tabindex="604"></font></td>
    <td style="height: 23px; width: 129px;" class="style7"><font face="Arial" size="2">
    <strong><font size="2">$ </font></strong>
    <!--webbot bot="Validation" s-data-type="Number" s-number-separators=",." --><input type="integer" name="RentSF_Tenant1" id="rentsqft1"  OnFocus="calcRentSQFTOne()"   onblur="this.value = '$' + formatNumber(this.value, 0, 0, true)" readonly="readonly" size="11" tabindex="605"></font></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
&nbsp;

<p><font face="Arial" size="2">
 <input type="submit" value="Save" name="Save" tabindex="999" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; width: 65px; height: 29px;"></font></p>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function calcRentSQFTOne(){
    SquareFeet1 = document.getElementById("sqft1").value;
    AnnualRent1 = document.getElementById("annualrent1").value;

    document.getElementById("rentsqft1").value = 
                    (AnnualRent1 * 1) 
                                          / (SquareFeet1 * 1);


 }


 //

 function formatNumber(number, digits, decimalPlaces, withCommas)
 {
    number       = number.toString();
var simpleNumber = '';

// Strips out the dollar sign and commas.
for (var i = 0; i < number.length; ++i)
{
    if ("0123456789.".indexOf(number.charAt(i)) >= 0)
        simpleNumber += number.charAt(i);
}

number = parseFloat(simpleNumber);

if (isNaN(number))      number     = 0;
if (withCommas == null) withCommas = false;
if (digits     == 0)    digits     = 1;

var integerPart = (decimalPlaces > 0 ? Math.floor(number) : Math.round(number));
var string      = "";

for (var i = 0; i < digits || integerPart > 0; ++i)
{
    // Insert a comma every three digits.
    if (withCommas && string.match(/^\d\d\d/))
        string = "," + string;

    string      = (integerPart % 10) + string;
    integerPart = Math.floor(integerPart / 10);
}

if (decimalPlaces > 0)
{
    number -= Math.floor(number);
    number *= Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);

    string += "." + formatNumber(number, decimalPlaces, 0);
 }

 return Math.round(input*100)/100 + "$";

 }





 function calcNRA1(){
    SquareFeet1 = document.getElementById("sqft1").value;
    TSF = document.getElementById("TotalSF").value;

    document.getElementById("NRA1").value = 
                    (SquareFeet1 * 1)/(TSF * 1) * 100
                                            + "%" ;                                

 }


 </script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: You should `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` your input values as they are just strings.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your script if addressed can make your script easier to debug and manage and make it less error prone.

1. You mix string concatenation with numeric computations. Instead convert all your values into numeric values, compute, then concatenate and format. Store calculations in numeric form and only format when you are ready to display.
2. Simplify your functions so it will do only one thing: convert formatted "number" into a numeric value OR convert a numeric value into a formatted string. Refactor `formatNumber` to do only one thing and make a second function to do the other (e.g. `formatNumber()` → `formatNumber()` and `convertToNumeric()`)

Example

```
// convert to numeric type, default to 0 if empty(?)
var SquareFeet1 = convertToNumeric(document.getElementById("sqft1").value);
var TSF = convertToNumeric(document.getElementById("TotalSF").value);

// calculate and store as numeric values
var nra = SquareFeet1 / TSF * 100;

// format and concatenate for display
var nraInput = document.getElementById("NRA1");
if (nra > 0) {
    nraInput.value = formatNumber(nra) + "%" ;
}
else {
    nraInput.value = "";
}
```

Comment: This seems to still give me a Nan when a comma is entered in any of the values.   ie 10,000

Comment: Which field and which of your functions or calculations is giving you NaN? The browser's debug console (F12 usually) will help you determine that.